# Push http2 all CSS asset files using Varnish regex

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, fastly, fastly-vcl

I'm using Varnish (fastly) and http2 to push `css` and `js` files. I want to push all `css`, `js`, `png` files.

My current configuration pushes only specified files from a given path:

```
  if (fastly_info.is_h2 && req.url ~ "pl_PL")
  {
    h2.push("/bootstrap-theme/app.css");
    h2.push("/bootstrap-theme/app.js");
  }
```

Is it possible to confiture VCL file so it will push all stylesheets, javascript and images?

I was trying to set up something like this but no luck.

```
  if (fastly_info.is_h2)
  {
    h2.push("\.(png|jpg|css|js)$");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.
However they do not recommend this practice anymore to push resources:
https://developer.fastly.com/reference/vcl/functions/tls-and-http/h2-push/

Comment: After more research I came to the same conclusion. Thank you for reassurance